# Can I use the orderby linq keyword with a comparer?

Tags: .net, linq

I was looking at the 101 LInQ examples [1] and they imply that I can use a Comparer with the LInQ orderby feature. But in the example, they punt and use an extension method. My question is, can I use a comparer within my Language Integrated Query?

[1] http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SQL-Ordering-Operators-050af19e#OrderBycomparer

Update: What I am looking for is actual language integration of my query. Something like the following would be nice:

```
string[] words = { "aPPLE", "AbAcUs", "bRaNcH", "BlUeBeRrY", "ClOvEr", "cHeRry" }; 
var sortedWords = from x in words
                  orderby (x,y) => string.Compare(x,y)
                  select x;
```

Or more concisely:

```
string[] words = { "aPPLE", "AbAcUs", "bRaNcH", "BlUeBeRrY", "ClOvEr", "cHeRry" }; 
var sortedWords = from x in words
                  orderby string.Compare
                  select x;
```

Comment: Well, all (or at least most) of Linq is extension methods.  Are you talking about getting rid of the Lambda?

Comment: I should refine this to say that I realize that there are two parts of LInQ, which makes things difficult to talk about. There are the Linq libraries, which consist of mostly extension methods and Linq providers. And then there is the language integration. I am curious about the language integration portion of this. Is there a way to specify a comparison mechanism without calling a library method?

Comment: If by "library method" you mean lambdas, then no.  The "query syntax" just gets converted by the compiler into extension method calls (or more precisely to calls to the static methods).  There's no way to enhance it that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 4):

Using their example:

```
string[] words = { "aPPLE", "AbAcUs", "bRaNcH", "BlUeBeRrY", "ClOvEr", "cHeRry" }; 

var sortedWords = words.OrderBy(a => a, new CaseInsensitiveComparer());
```

if you want to shorten it to

```
var sortedWords = words.OrderBy(new CaseInsensitiveComparer());
```

You could create another extension method that bypasses the Lambda:

```
public static IOrderedEnumerable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, IComparer<T> comparer)
{
    return source.OrderBy(a=>a, comparer);
}
```

Either way, it is (in my opinion) not a big enough gain (8 characters saved?) to bypass the standard lambda syntax.

Comment: Agreed on your conclusion.  Creating multiple Comparators, one for each possible method of comparison, is a very Java way of doing things.  One of the big benefits of lambdas is that you can avoid creating one-time-use function-objects everywhere.

Comment: This is a good answer, I guess my question was more of a rant that this has not yet been integrated into the language.